# Как подключиться к сокету? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, websocket

Есть вебсокет на localhost'е, при попытке подключиться к нему получаю такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:9243");
```

Сайт не мой, доступа к нему не имею (скрипт работает через Tampermonkey). Есть какие-то варианты подключиться к сокету?

Comment: Возможно тебе поможет вот такой ответ по аналогичному вопросу - https://qna.habr.com/q/1044414

Answer (score 1):

Такая ошибка обычно возникает, когда браузер блокирует запрос из-за ограничений безопасности.

Возможно, проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь подключиться к веб-сокету по безопасному протоколу (wss), но на локалхосте нет сертификата. Попробуйте вместо wss использовать протокол ws:

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9243");
```